# Particular hangouts windows not opening

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

When I click on a person's name in the chat list, sometimes an invisible chat window opens. I can see the outline of the window, but nothing else. In every session, 3-4 such windows open. I have cleared cache, cookies. I have refreshed browser, restarted everything. Deleted Adblock extension thinking it could be a pop up issue, but nothing has worked. I have the same issue, and every time I need to chat with someone, it can happen at random, so I refresh Gmail and hope that the person I want to talk to at that point, will not end up being such a window. If it is, I refresh again. Sometimes I need to do this 3-4 times to be able to talk to one person.

[image: invisible-hangouts-window]

Comment: Which browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)(updated it 2 days ago) on a MBA running OS X 10.11.4. The problem persisted before and after the update.

Comment: @SathyaVibhu Are you using any Adblockers? And I have had similar problems with bad internet connection. Is the internet connection stable and fast?

Comment: I've deleted Adblock. It seemed to be fine once or twice after that. But its still persistent. Internet connection seems fine, at both home and office.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of 92072. Additionally this is a minor bug in Hangouts that was fixed months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well using Chrome on my MacBook Pro.
Completely restarting Chrome fixed the problem for me and I haven't seen it return.

Comment: Did you uninstall and reinstall? I had an older version of Chrome where I had this issue and updated it. I think what I'm using is the latest version. Simply restarting Chrome hasn't worked.